# How to move return type to next line in AppCode in function declaration?

Tags: ios, swift, jetbrains-ide, appcode

How to setup code style in AppCode in order to move return type to next line if the declaration is too long?

Here is an example:

```
public func requestString(_ method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod,
    _ url: URLConvertible,
    parameters: [String: Any]? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: [String: String]? = nil)
    -> Observable<(HTTPURLResponse, String)> {
    return SessionManager.default.rx.responseString(
        method,
        url,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: encoding,
        headers: headers
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following settings should do exactly what you need

[image: Settings]

Comment: What I meant was to change method declaration parameters, not call arguments.